# expand the width of a ul if the text overflows

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to expand a ul li ul (drop down) if the text of ul li ul li goes outside the width of the box?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KAVzf/1/

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove all references to `width: 100%` from your menu (`#midwrap #nav li ul`, `#midwrap #nav li ul li`, `#midwrap #nav li ul li a`)

**Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/KAVzf/13/**

#### Update

To resolve the issue with only the text being highlighted in the sub-menu on hover you need to add the following CSS to `#midwrap #nav li ul li`:

```
#midwrap #nav li ul li {
    ...
    float: none;
    display: block;
    ...
}
```

**Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/KAVzf/22/**

Comment: @A.K could you expand on what is "not working as expected"? I have just updated my answer to remove all `width: 100%` references so maybe this resolves the issue you have found.

Answer (score 1):

Check this

http://jsfiddle.net/KAVzf/14/

Remove width 100% from `#midwrap #nav li ul li {}`   and `#midwrap #nav li ul {}`

Have width 100% for anchors only.

Comment: Hey, thanks for this, only problem is now, on the shorter ones the hover effect (color change) only applies to the width of the text rather than the entire box if this makes sense?

Comment: I checked and did not find any issue. Can you please show a screenshot of the issue?

Comment: Sure, this here is it with the mouse hovered over the text "tt" http://imgur.com/ZmoX3

Comment: @MyHeadHurts I checked your jsfiddle output. The issue is not there. But in my case also I am not getting the issue.

Comment: @Rain If you hover `Accommodation > tt` (you must hover over the actual `tt` text) then only `tt` will be highlighted. I get the same on both my original answer and your answer (in FF). It is strange that you are not able to reproduce as this is actually the expected behaviour since `float` causes a div to wrap to fit its content rather than the remaining space

Comment: Yes, in my end I am not getting this issue.